# matlab functions

Tags: function, matlab

helo, I have the following function called stat.m

```
function [mean,stdev] = stat(x)
n = length(x)
mean = sum(x)/n
stdev = sqrt(sum((x-mean).^2/n))
```

I defined x as a vector which is  `[1,2,5,7,9]`

how come when I type `a = stat(x)`, matlab returns `a = 5` for the last line  at command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get both return values, you have to do this:

```
[a, b] = stat(x);
```

If you just do `a = stat(x)`, MATLAB interprets that to mean that you only want the first return value.

Answer (score 2):

because `a` gets the first argument `mean`

try to call it `[a,b] = stat(x)`